# What is the Standard way to Achieve this grid in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I'm trying to create:

[image: UI Im trying to create]

I'm Trying to Create this grid layout (ignoring Entry box right now) but I'm Having issue in stretching the 5th row having 5 columns equally. So far, I have achieved this.

[image: so far my output]

Code I have coded so far is given below but do let me know the standard way to achieve this grid.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

num = 1
for i in range(0, 3):
    for j in range(0, 3):
        tk.Button(frame, text=num).grid(row=i, column=j, sticky='nsew')
        num += 1
        frame.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
        frame.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)

tk.Button(frame, text='-').grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='nsew')
tk.Button(frame, text=0).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky='nsew')
tk.Button(frame, text='.').grid(row=4, column=2, sticky='nsew')
frame.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)

frame2 = tk.Frame(frame)
frame2.grid(row=5, columnspan=3)

frame2.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame2.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
frame2.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
frame2.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
frame2.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)

tk.Button(frame2, text='+').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
tk.Button(frame2, text='-').grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')
tk.Button(frame2, text='*').grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='nsew')
tk.Button(frame2, text='/').grid(row=0, column=3, sticky='nsew')
tk.Button(frame2, text='=').grid(row=0, column=4, sticky='nsew')


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I guess all you need to do is to span that frame. Try `frame2.grid(row=5, columnspan=3, sticky='we')`

Comment: @Thingamabobs 5th row just sticks to left using your statement

Comment: @toyotaSupra , Thanks, it was my dumb mistake I didn't give columns of operator row a weight of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followed by @Thingambobs. `frame2.grid(row=5, columnspan=3, sticky='we')`

- On line 12, add `width=5` for Button widget to suit your need.
- If you like to add an `Entry` widget. Just add on line 17 and 18. See
  snippet.
- On line 28, then add button for "CLR" `tk.Button(frame, text='CLR', width=5).grid(row=6,column=0,columnspan=5, sticky='we')`
- These five `Button` widgets, change `sticky` to `sticky='we'`

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
#root.grid_propagate()

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

num = 1
for i in range(0, 3):
    for j in range(0, 3):
        tk.Button(frame, text=num, width=5).grid(row=i+1, column=j, sticky='nsew')
        num += 1
        frame.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
        frame.rowconfigure(i, weight=5)

entry = tk.Entry(frame, width=25)
entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky='we')

tk.Button(frame, text='-').grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='nsew')
tk.Button(frame, text=0).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky='nsew')
tk.Button(frame, text='.').grid(row=4, column=2, sticky='nsew')
frame.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)

frame2 = tk.Frame(frame)
frame2.grid(row=5, columnspan=3, sticky='we')

tk.Button(frame, text='CLR').grid(row=6, column=0,columnspan=5, sticky='we') 

tk.Button(frame2, text='+', width=5).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='we')
tk.Button(frame2, text='-', width=5).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='we')
tk.Button(frame2, text='*', width=5).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='we')
tk.Button(frame2, text='/', width=5).grid(row=0, column=3, sticky='we')
tk.Button(frame2, text='=', width=5).grid(row=0, column=4, sticky='we')

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Tysm!! Really Appreciate it

Comment: Salaam, my friend. Glad I could help.